# can declared functions be called without a body

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Can you call a function that has no body but is declared in the header in your code?? Please read below for my situation.

I am learning c++ so if my terminology is off then you know why. Any how, I am reading this book called "Advanced 2D Game Development" so if anyone's read the book then maybe they can help me out. In c++ he set 4 extern functions in Advanced2D.h

```
extern bool game_preload();
extern bool game_init(HWND);
extern void game_update();
extern void game_end();
```

Later on down the line he calls on them several time's in a class but never gives them a body. What he is eventually trying to do with all the code is compile it into lib file so other projects could include it and actually use those 4 methods.

He wanted me to go to the solutions properties/General/Output Directory and add this in both the Release and Debug Configuration

```
$(ProjectDir)..\lib\Advance2D.lib // It didn't work. Still added the libs at default location
```

Only to use those methods above in another project like this . This is when declarative methods get their bodies.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "..\Engine\Advanced2D.h"
bool game_preload()
{
     //display engine version in a message box
     g_engine->message(g_engine->getVersionText(), "TEST ENGINE");
     //return fail to terminate the engine
     return false;
}

bool game_init(HWND hwnd) { return 0;}
void game_update() {}
void game_end() {}
```

The only problem now is that I receive a linker error

```
1>winmain.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl game_preload(void)" (?game_preload@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function _WinMain@16
1>c:\Engine\msvc8\Advance2D\Advance2D\..\lib\Advance2D.lib\Advance2D.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

If I don't comment out those methods being used in the first project then the project never gets compiled ?

The guy insist that I shouldn't receive any linker errors at the time of compiling it. And I quote the following

> Assuming you have typed the code into
>   the specified files without any
>   mistakes, you should be able to
>   compile the engine project. There
>   should be no dependencies for the
>   engine because the compiler assumes
>   that you will provide the needed libs
>   at link time (when you create an
>   executable using the engine’s lib).
>   This is a rather complex issue that
>   we’ll examine again over the next
>   several chapters as we enhance the
>   engine with new modules and
>   functionality. You should not see any
>   linker errors, only compiler errors if
>   you have made a mistake while typing
>   in the code.

the following is advanced2D header

```
// Advanced2D Engine
// Main header file
#ifndef _ADVANCED2D_H
#define _ADVANCED2D_H 1
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>
#include <dxerr.h>
#include "Timer.h"
#define VERSION_MAJOR 1
#define VERSION_MINOR 0
#define REVISION 0

#pragma comment(lib,"d3d9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"d3dx9.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

//external variables and functions
extern bool gameover;
extern bool game_preload();
extern bool game_init(HWND);
extern void game_update();
extern void game_end();

namespace Advanced2D
{
    class Engine {
        private:
            int p_versionMajor, p_versionMinor, p_revision;
            HWND p_windowHandle;
            LPDIRECT3D9 p_d3d;
            LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 p_device;
            LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 p_backbuffer;
            LPD3DXSPRITE p_sprite_handler;
            std::string p_apptitle;
            bool p_fullscreen;
            int p_screenwidth;
            int p_screenheight;
            int p_colordepth;
            bool p_pauseMode;
            D3DCOLOR p_ambientColor;
            bool p_maximizeProcessor;
            Timer p_coreTimer;
            long p_frameCount_core;
            long p_frameRate_core;
            Timer p_realTimer;
            long p_frameCount_real;
            long p_frameRate_real;
        public:
            Engine();
            virtual ~Engine();
            int Init(int width, int height, int colordepth, bool fullscreen);
            void Close();
            void Update();
            void message(std::string message, std::string title = "ADVANCED 2D");
            void fatalerror(std::string message, std::string title = "FATAL ERROR");
            void Shutdown();
            void ClearScene(D3DCOLOR color);
            void SetDefaultMaterial();
            void SetAmbient(D3DCOLOR colorvalue);
            int RenderStart();
            int RenderStop();
            int Release();
            //accessor/mutator functions expose the private variables
            bool isPaused() { return this->p_pauseMode; }
            void setPaused(bool value) { this->p_pauseMode = value; }
            LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 getDevice() { return this->p_device; }
            LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 getBackBuffer() { return this->p_backbuffer; }
            LPD3DXSPRITE getSpriteHandler() { return this->p_sprite_handler; }
            void setWindowHandle(HWND hwnd) { this->p_windowHandle = hwnd; }
            HWND getWindowHandle() { return this->p_windowHandle; }
            std::string getAppTitle() { return this->p_apptitle; }
            void setAppTitle(std::string value) { this->p_apptitle = value; }
            int getVersionMajor() { return this->p_versionMajor; }
            int getVersionMinor() { return this->p_versionMinor; }
            int getRevision() { return this->p_revision; }
            std::string getVersionText();
            long getFrameRate_core() { return this->p_frameRate_core; };
            long getFrameRate_real() { return this->p_frameRate_real; };
            int getScreenWidth() { return this->p_screenwidth; }
            void setScreenWidth(int value) { this->p_screenwidth = value; }
            int getScreenHeight() { return this->p_screenheight; }
            void setScreenHeight(int value) { this->p_screenheight = value; }
            int getColorDepth() { return this->p_colordepth; }
            void setColorDepth(int value) { this->p_colordepth = value; }
            bool getFullscreen() { return this->p_fullscreen; }
            void setFullscreen(bool value) { this->p_fullscreen = value; }
            bool getMaximizeProcessor() { return this->p_maximizeProcessor; }
            void setMaximizeProcessor(bool value) { this->p_maximizeProcessor = value;}
    }; //class
}; //namespace
//define the global engine object (visible everywhere!)
extern Advanced2D::Engine *g_engine;
#endif
```

Advanced2d class

```
// Advanced2D Engine
// Main source code file
//includes
#include "Advanced2D.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <list>
#include "winmain.h"

namespace Advanced2D
{
    Engine::Engine()
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
        p_maximizeProcessor = false;
        p_frameCount_core = 0;
        p_frameRate_core = 0;
        p_frameCount_real = 0;
        p_frameRate_real = 0;
        p_ambientColor = D3DCOLOR_RGBA(255,255,255, 0);
        p_windowHandle = 0;
        p_pauseMode = false;
        p_versionMajor = VERSION_MAJOR;
        p_versionMinor = VERSION_MINOR;
        p_revision = REVISION;
        //set default values
        this->setAppTitle("Advanced2D");
        this->setScreenWidth(640);
        this->setScreenHeight(480);
        this->setColorDepth(32);
        this->setFullscreen(false);
        //window handle must be set later on for DirectX!
        this->setWindowHandle(0);
    }

    Engine::~Engine()
    {
        if (this->p_device) this->p_device->Release();
        if (this->p_d3d) this->p_d3d->Release();
    }

    std::string Engine::getVersionText()
    {
        std::ostringstream s;
        s << "Advanced2D Engine v" << p_versionMajor << "." << p_versionMinor
        << "." << p_revision;
        return s.str();
    }

    void Engine::message(std::string message, std::string title)
    {
        MessageBox(0, message.c_str(), title.c_str(), 0);
    }

    void Engine::fatalerror(std::string message, std::string title)
    {
        this->message(message,title);
        Shutdown();
    }

    int Engine::Init(int width, int height, int colordepth, bool fullscreen)
    {
        //initialize Direct3D

        this->p_d3d = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

        if (this->p_d3d == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }

        //get system desktop color depth
        D3DDISPLAYMODE dm;
        this->p_d3d->GetAdapterDisplayMode(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, &dm);

        //set configuration options for Direct3D
        D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS d3dpp;
        ZeroMemory(&d3dpp, sizeof(d3dpp));
        d3dpp.Windowed = (!fullscreen);
        d3dpp.SwapEffect = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
        d3dpp.EnableAutoDepthStencil = TRUE;
        d3dpp.AutoDepthStencilFormat = D3DFMT_D16;
        d3dpp.PresentationInterval = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
        d3dpp.BackBufferFormat = dm.Format;
        d3dpp.BackBufferCount = 1;
        d3dpp.BackBufferWidth = width;
        d3dpp.BackBufferHeight = height;
        d3dpp.hDeviceWindow = p_windowHandle;

        //create Direct3D device
        this->p_d3d->CreateDevice(
        D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT,
        D3DDEVTYPE_HAL,
        this->p_windowHandle,
        D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING,
        &d3dpp,
        &this->p_device);
        if (this->p_device == NULL) return 0;

        //clear the backbuffer to black
        this->ClearScene(D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0));

        //create pointer to the back buffer
        this->p_device->GetBackBuffer(0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &this->p_backbuffer);

        //use ambient lighting and z-buffering
        this->p_device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_ZENABLE, TRUE);
        this->p_device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_FILLMODE, D3DFILL_SOLID);
        this->SetAmbient(this->p_ambientColor);

        //initialize 2D renderer
        HRESULT result = D3DXCreateSprite(this->p_device, &this->p_sprite_handler);
        if (result != D3D_OK) return 0;
        //call game initialization extern function
        //if (!game_init(this->getWindowHandle())) return 0;
        //set a default material
        SetDefaultMaterial();
        return 1;
    }


    void Engine::SetDefaultMaterial()
    {
        D3DMATERIAL9 mat;
        memset(&mat, 0, sizeof(mat));
        mat.Diffuse.r = 1.0f;
        mat.Diffuse.g = 1.0f;
        mat.Diffuse.b = 1.0f;
        mat.Diffuse.a = 1.0f;
        p_device->SetMaterial(&mat);
    }

    void Engine::ClearScene(D3DCOLOR color)
    {
        this->p_device->Clear(0, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET | D3DCLEAR_ZBUFFER,
        color, 1.0f, 0);
    }

    void Engine::SetAmbient(D3DCOLOR colorvalue)
    {
        this->p_ambientColor = colorvalue;
        this->p_device->SetRenderState(D3DRS_AMBIENT, this->p_ambientColor);
    }
    int Engine::RenderStart()
    {
        if (!this->p_device) return 0;
        if (this->p_device->BeginScene() != D3D_OK) return 0;
        return 1;
    }
    int Engine::RenderStop()
    {
        if (!this->p_device) return 0;
        if (this->p_device->EndScene() != D3D_OK) return 0;
        if (p_device->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) != D3D_OK) return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    void Engine::Shutdown()
    {
        gameover = true;
    }

    void Engine::Update()
    {
        static Timer timedUpdate;
        //calculate core framerate
        p_frameCount_core++;
        if (p_coreTimer.stopwatch(999)) {
        p_frameRate_core = p_frameCount_core;
        p_frameCount_core = 0;
        }
        //fast update with no timing
        game_update();

        //update with 60fps timing
        if (!timedUpdate.stopwatch(14)) {
            if (!this->getMaximizeProcessor())
            {
                Sleep(1);
            }
        }
        else {
            //calculate real framerate
            p_frameCount_real++;

            if (p_realTimer.stopwatch(999)) {
                p_frameRate_real = p_frameCount_real;
                p_frameCount_real = 0;
            }
            //begin rendering
            this->RenderStart();
            //done rendering
            this->RenderStop();
        }
    }
    void Engine::Close()
    {
        game_end();
    }
} //namespace
```

And here is the WinMain

```
#include <sstream>
#include "winmain.h"
#include "Advanced2D.h"
//macro to read the key states
#define KEY_DOWN(vk) ((GetAsyncKeyState(vk) & 0x8000)?1:0)
HINSTANCE g_hInstance;
HWND g_hWnd;
int g_nCmdShow;
//declare global engine object
Advanced2D::Engine *g_engine;
bool gameover;


//window event callback function
LRESULT WINAPI WinProc( HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam )
{
    switch( msg )
    {
    case WM_QUIT:
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
    gameover = true;
    break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc( hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int
nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));
    g_hInstance = hInstance;
    g_nCmdShow = nCmdShow;
    DWORD dwStyle, dwExStyle;
    RECT windowRect;
    /**
    * Create engine object first!
    **/
    g_engine = new Advanced2D::Engine();
    //let main program have a crack at things before window is created
    if (!game_preload()) {
        MessageBox(g_hWnd, "Error in game preload!", "Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    //get window caption string from engine
    char title[255];
    sprintf_s(title, "%s", g_engine->getAppTitle().c_str());
    //set window dimensions
    windowRect.left = (long)0;
    windowRect.right = (long)g_engine->getScreenWidth();
    windowRect.top = (long)0;
    windowRect.bottom = (long)g_engine->getScreenHeight();
    //create the window class structure
    WNDCLASSEX wc;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    //fill the struct with info
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WinProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = NULL;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = title;
    wc.hIconSm = NULL;
    //set up the window with the class info
    RegisterClassEx(&wc);
    //set up the screen in windowed or fullscreen mode?
    if (g_engine->getFullscreen())
    {
        DEVMODE dm;
        memset(&dm, 0, sizeof(dm));
        dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);
        dm.dmPelsWidth = g_engine->getScreenWidth();
        dm.dmPelsHeight = g_engine->getScreenHeight();
        dm.dmBitsPerPel = g_engine->getColorDepth();
        dm.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;
        if (ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, CDS_FULLSCREEN) != DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Display mode failed", NULL, MB_OK);
        g_engine->setFullscreen(false);
        }
        dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        ShowCursor(FALSE);
        }
        else {
        dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
        }
        //adjust window to true requested size
        AdjustWindowRectEx(&windowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);
        //create the program window
        g_hWnd = CreateWindowEx( 0,
        title, //window class
        title, //title bar
        dwStyle | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS,
        0, 0, //x,y coordinate
        windowRect.right - windowRect.left, //width of the window
        windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top, //height of the window
        0, //parent window
        0, //menu
        g_hInstance, //application instance
        0); //window parameters
        //was there an error creating the window?
        if (!g_hWnd) {
        MessageBox(g_hWnd, "Error creating program window!", "Error", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }
    //display the window
    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, g_nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(g_hWnd);
    //initialize the engine
    g_engine->setWindowHandle(g_hWnd);
    if (!g_engine->Init(g_engine->getScreenWidth(), g_engine->getScreenHeight(),
    g_engine->getColorDepth(), g_engine->getFullscreen())) {
    MessageBox(g_hWnd, "Error initializing the engine", "Error", MB_OK);
    return 0;
    }
    // main message loop
    gameover = false;
    while (!gameover)
    {
        while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        g_engine->Update();
    }

    if (g_engine->getFullscreen()) {
        ShowCursor(TRUE);
    }
    g_engine->Close();
    delete g_engine;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: On the terminology: your use of 'declare' is correct. The term you are missing is 'define'. Defining a function or method is providing an implementation (the body in curly braces).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `extern` keyword specifies that the function will be implemented in a compilation object external to the one you're in - usually via a lib or other object. If you were to declare a variable in global scope in one cpp file (outside any function body) you can only reference it using external {variable declaration} in another cpp file - so that the compiler knows not to expect the function/variable be defined but know it exists.

What's happening here by the sounds of things is that the object you are linking to is not actually being linked in - it should be. The above answer tells you how to - I'm not fast enough! From your question it seems like you have the source to this second project and may possibly need to built it yourself - I don't know, of course, but if the .lib doesn't exist then you will need to.

Comment: Take a look at the advanced2d class. If you look towards the bottom, you will see game_update(); and game_end(); they are 2 externs methods that are being declared in the advanced2d.h . They are being called but they have no bodies. So in order for the lib file to exist, I must compile it as is and that is when I get a error. I could comment it out and then it would work. but then I would be including a library that is missing those lines of code.

Comment: I understand what the extern keyword is. What I dont understand is why it wont compile, when the Arthur insist it should. I have narrowed the issue down to those couple lines. game_end(); and game_update(); 2 functions that are being called without a body and the only thing causing the whole application to throw a error.

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I suppose you are using some version of MS Visual C++. Make sure you have Advance2D.lib in the ProjectProperties -> Linker-> Input -> Additional Dependencies field. Also add the path to this library in ProjectProperties -> Linker-> General -> Additional Library Directories. It is not required that you change the default output path of the engine project. BTW, if you are a beginner to C++, better read something like [The C++ Programming Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html) or [Thinking In C++](http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html) before you dive into "Advanced" stuff.

Comment: well the problem is I cannot compile the project without commenting out pieces of the extern functions within the Advanced2D class. because the class are calling on the functions but their bodies are never made. therefore I recieve the error.

Comment: see my response to ninefingers.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is a linker error, not a compiler error. Your code compiles fine, but the linker cannot generate the executable until all referenced functions have a body. The linker either doesn't know about the library that contains the function bodies, or that library does not contain them.

In the first case you need to change your project settings and specify the correct names and locations, Vijay described that already.

In the second case you should check the exported symbols of that library. If the library was compiled as C++, the names of the functions could have been mangled for typesafety (need to be specified as exported in the library to prevent that), or they could have a different signature and you have to change your extern statements. VC has a tool to display the information of libraries, I think it was called dumpbin.

Comment: That's why I think the guy who wrote the book didn't edit correctly. Because he wants me to compile some code, only to turn into a lib file. But the problem is that I can not compile the code because of lack of definitions for the extern methods. He wants other projects to include those lib files and then will the methods be defined. But I can't get to that point if I am getting errors

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add in case you were still stuck on this issue or if anyone else finds this thread and wants some additional troubleshooting while working through the Advanced 2D Game Dev book.

On p.16 where he's going over the VS setup for the engine, make sure that you not only change the Target Extension to .lib, but also ensure the Configuration Type is set to Static Library (.lib), not Dynamic Library (.dll).

If you leave the Configuration Type as Dynamic Library, you'll see the LNK2019 error for the extern functions because the VC++ linker expects these functions to have a definition in order for a working DLL file to be produced. When you compile a Static Library, the actual definitions for the externalized variables, functions, etc, do not need to be present until you're finally linking everything together into a DLL or EXE (as is done in subsequent projects throughout the book).

Some links that might be helpful on this topic:

Using extern to Specify Linkage : msdn.microsoft.com/en-us + /library/0603949d.aspx

Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Static Library: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us + /library/ms235627%28VS.80%29.aspx

Microsoft Visual C++ Static and Dynamic Libraries: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/libraries1.aspx

Hope you find this info useful!

*note: sorry about the crazy msdn links above, apparently I can't post more than one link until I have some more StackOverflow cred.